# Call java file using relative path in bash shell

Tags: java, command-line

```
bash
/Desktop/Lab 3$ cd Stemmer
/Desktop/Lab 3/Stemmer$ java Stemmer
/Desktop/Lab 3/Stemmer$ cd ..
/Desktop/Lab 3$ java Stemmer/Stemmer
Error: Could not find or load main class Stemmer.Stemmer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stemmer (wrong name: Stemmer/Stemmer)
/Desktop/Lab 3$
```

Why doesn't java run `Stemmer` when I specify a relative path?

It seems to have run the program when I was in the directory, but I want java to run `Stemmer` as it did when I was in the directory that it was located in.

Could someone explain what is happening here please.

Comment: Do you have a file named `Stemmer.java`? What is in this file?

Comment: I see I made some assumptions about what you are trying to do by answering below. FYI, it helps a lot when you ask a question to include all the necessary details for us to reproduce the error you are asking about. In this case, we need to see the contents of `Stemmer.java` at the very least. Also, the detail about how you are writing a Linux script to run this Java program would give some context that you can edit into the original question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 broad options:

### You are trying to write an application in java

Then you need an IDE to develop it in, and a build system to produce the distributables, in the form of a jar file. There is no point or reason to trying to run this 'on the command line' the way you are. You need packages and a project definition.

### You are just toying around for now, writing some basic code in a single source file.

Then just run the source file. This is a feature introduced in, I think, java11. Before that, this model of writing (stuff some lines in a source file and run it right away) is not what java itself is good at, only IDEs do that properly.

Starting with java11:

```
java Stemmer/Stemmer.java
```

works great, and no need to (re)compile anything. `java` will take care of it.

### Explanation

When you run a Java program, you specify the **class name** including the fully specified **package**, not the file path.

You read this answer before, and then proceeded to completely ignore it and try `java Stemmer.Stemmer` which obviously doesn't work.

The **class** you have is named `Stemmer`, and it is in the unnamed package. Thus, to run it, `java Stemmer` is how to do this. It's not a file name. `Stemmer.Stemmer` is not java-ese for 'run the class file `Stemmer` in the subdirectory `Stemmer`, and 'package' is not java-ese for 'directory on the filesystem'.

The classpath root for your Stemmer class is its own directory, as you are not using any packages. the default classpath is the current directory. It is **not possible** to run the Stemmer class file without having its root on the classpath, so if `/Desktop/Lab 3/Stemmer` is not on the cp, you can't do it. So let's fix this:

```
java -cp '/Desktop/Lab 3/Stemmer' Stemmer
```

and that'll work fine.

More generally, using the unnamed package is a bad idea, and trying to run raw class files is similarly a bad idea - use an IDE for development, and a build system to build projects.

These rules and caveats all make perfect sense when writing a 'real' project (one you check into source control, and eventually deploy someplace or ship as a product to other users). But it's onerous and a tad ridiculous if just messing around. That's exactly why (these days) you can just specify a *path* to a java source file, which seems to be what you want to do. So, do that.

Comment: Thank you. `java Stemmer/Stemmer.java` seems to work ok. Just thought I'd mention that the Java program I am trying to run wasn't written by me, and I am trying to run it as part of an executable "shell script" in Linux. It seemed like it would be inefficient to move into the directory to call files outside the directory to use them with the program, which is why I wanted to call the program from outside the directory. Sorry I didn't make that clear in my question.

Comment: @SuperS Then the solution is to set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, either with `export` or with the `-cp` flag as described in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you run a Java program, you specify the **class name** including the fully specified **package**, not the file path. This means that you separate the package "path" with dots, not slash. If you compiled a file named `Stemmer.java` that is in a folder named `Stemmer` and has `package Stemmer` as the first line, then you do

```
java Stemmer.Stemmer
```

Comment: Typing `java Stemmer.Stemmer` just does `Error: Could not find or load main class Stemmer.Stemmer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stemmer (wrong name: Stemmer/Stemmer)`, as before.

Comment: @SuperS It sounds like you have a file named `Stemmer.java` but it doesn't have a `class Stemmer` declared in it. And do you have `package Stemmer` at the top of the file?